# Merge two dataframes (same columns), different timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Dataframes as follows:

Dataframe 1

```
timestamp_read  base
1508025600009   A
1508025600088   G
1508025600156   C
1508025600200   T
1508025600257   T
1508025600307   C
1508025600403   G
1508025600476   G
1508025600550   D
1508025600596   G
1508025600606   D
1508025600658   G
```

Dataframe 2

```
timestamp_read  base    
1508025600009   A   
1508025600101   G   
1508025600104   C   
1508025600174   T   
1508025600233   T   
1508025600233   T   Additional T
1508025600238   C   
1508025600266   G   
1508025600268   G   Missing D
1508025600285   G   
1508025600393   D   
1508025600455   G   
1508025600460   A   Additional A
```

timestamp_read is an epoch time. Dataframe 1 and 2 should be identical but they are not as diagostics are running across two separate machines, so there is a degree of latency. Sometimes results may be missed on one machine and not the other and vice versa. What would be the best way of merging these two dataframes, accounting for this latency differential. I suspect the solution may involve massively parallel signature sequencing but am keen to hear solutions.

Desired Output:

```
timestamp_read  base    
1508025600009   A   
1508025600101   G   
1508025600104   C   
1508025600174   T   
1508025600233   T   
1508025600233   T   Additional T
1508025600238   C   
1508025600266   G   
1508025600268   G   Missing D
1508025600272   D   Synthetically generated timestamp based on 
                    distance from other points in original timeseries 
                    is optional.
1508025600285   G   
1508025600393   D   
1508025600455   G   
1508025600460   A   Additional A
```

Comment: What do you expect the results to look like?  It doesn't seem that row 1 of `df1` is the same as row 4 in `df2`.  They are of different `TYPE`.  Do you want to keep one and not the other?  Which one do you want to keep?

Comment: I think you are looking for `merge_asof` cant say how to implement without knowing the expected output.

Comment: @piRSquared - Have edited and simplified the question to make it clearer.

Comment: In output are data from `df1` column `base`?

Comment: @jezrael I dont understand your question

Comment: I guess that dataframe1 and dataframe2 are possible to miss the data simultaneously. How can you detect it?  This problem requires some constraint to solve.

Comment: **example1** true_values= "TTTTTT" , df1_values="TTTT" , df2_values="TTTT". which "T" is missing?

Comment: **example2**  true_values="AGGTGT" df1_values ="AGGTT",df2_values ="AGTGT".  How can I regenerate true_values from df1_values and df2_values? I may regenerate something like "AGGTTGT","AGGTGTT". I can't specify the true pattern even such a simple input. Constraint is required.